# Debian: sftp-server still running after removing vsftpd?

Tags: debian, sftp, process, ftp

After i removed vsftpd from my new vserver with debian5, there is still some process called sftp-server running and managing ftp-connection.
How can i turn that off? Where does it came from?

Commented out following line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` now and still running:

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

`netstat -tulpen` output: (censored my IP through xx.xx.xxx.xxx)

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State         User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      102        2331605921  1343/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      105        2331610459  1538/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          2331606433  1379/apache2
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xxx.xxx:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      102        2331605880  1343/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      102        2331605866  1343/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          2331612861  1595/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      102        2331605922  1343/named
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      102        2331605862  1343/named
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          2331612863  1595/sshd
udp        0      0 xx.xx.xxx.xxx:53        0.0.0.0:*                           102        2331605867  1343/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           102        2331605864  1343/named
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                102        2331605849  1343/named
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sftp-server` (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is not a part of `ftp`. It's a part of `OpenSSH`.
You can turn it off in your ssh-config, usually in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Change the binary loaded to handle the sftp-sessions:

```
Subsystem sftp /bin/false
```

Don't forget to restart your sshd after the change:

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Comment: I commented out the line and restarted ssh and after that didn't worked whole server, but still can access through sftp-connection to server and it's still running.

Comment: I commented out this one:
`#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`. Forgotten anything?

Comment: Post the results from `sudo netstat -tulpen` in your opening post please.

Comment: Ok, sorry at first i edited your answer and somehow can't change it back. But output is posted in my question.

Comment: Did you restart the service after editing the settings? `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`

Comment: Yeah, like i said. At first just `ssh restart` (`sshd` doesn't exist) But no difference. (still able to login via sftp) So I restarted the whole server too, to be 100% sure everything is restarted, but still able to connect via sftp.

Comment: Ah, it dawned on me. If there is no setting for a particular option, it will use default. Instead of commenting the line out, try editing it to `Subsystem sftp /bin/false`

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now disabled. Is this now the best solution to disable the sftp-server?

Comment: Yes, you need to override the default.

Comment: Do i have to change the path for subsystem sftp if i want to use another sftp-server like vsftpd in future or how does that work then?

Comment: Look up the difference between SFTP, FTP & FTPS ;)